# TYPO3 extension backend enable jQuery file Problem

Tags: jquery, typo3-extensions

I am trying to use a jQuery file for the backend of my own extension.
In the `Backend/partial/News/FormField.html` I implemented the `f:be.container` viewhelper

```
<f:be.container
   includeJsFiles="{0:'{f:uri.resource(path: \'JS/jquery-3.2.1.min.js\',1:'{f:uri.resource(path: \'JS/crNews.js\')}'}">
<label for="header">
    <f:translate key="tx_crnews_domain_model_news.header" />
</label><br />
    <f:form.textfield property="header" id="header" size="100" /><br />
<label for="iFile">
    <f:translate key="tx_crnews_domain_model_news.i_file" />
</label><br />
    <f:if condition="{news}">
        <f:then>
            <f:image src='{news.iFile}' alt="image" width="200" /><br />
            <f:form.textfield property="iFile" size="100" /><br />
            <f:form.upload name="fInfo" id="fInfo" additionalAttributes="{accept='image/*'}" />
        </f:then>
        <f:else>
            <f:form.upload name="fInfo" id="fInfo" additionalAttributes="{accept='image/*'}" />
        </f:else>
    </f:if>
    <br />
<label for="iWidth">
    <f:translate key="tx_crnews_domain_model_news.i_width" />
</label><br />
    <f:form.textfield property="iWidth" id="iWidth" /><br />
<label for="iPos">
    <f:translate key="tx_crnews_domain_model_news.i_pos" />
</label><br />
    <f:form.select property="iPos" id="iPos" >
       <f:form.select.option value="left">links</f:form.select.option>
       <f:form.select.option value="right">rechts</f:form.select.option>
    </f:form.select><br />
<label for="text">
    <f:translate key="tx_crnews_domain_model_news.text" />
</label><br />
    <f:form.textarea property="text" id="text" cols="40" rows="15" /><br />
<label for="sDate">
    <f:translate key="tx_crnews_domain_model_news.s_date" />
</label><br />
    <f:form.textfield property="sDate" id="sDate" value="{news.sDate->f:format.date()}" /><br />
<label for="eDate">
    <f:translate key="tx_crnews_domain_model_news.e_date" />
</label><br />
<f:form.textfield type="datetime" property="eDate" id="eDate" class="form-control t3js-datetimepicker t3js-clearable" data="{date-type:'datetime',date-offset:'0'}" value="{eDate->f:format.date(format: 'd/m/Y')}" />
<span class="input-group-btn">
<label class="btn btn-default" for="eDate">
<span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
</label>
</span>
<!--    <f:form.textfield property="eDate" id="eDate" value="{news.eDate->f:format.date()}" /> -->
<br />

<fieldset id="fsAPIC">
    <legend>Vorschau</legend>
</fieldset

</f:be.container>
```

I also have included a jQuery file. Is it required?
and here is my simple crNews.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("start crNews");
        $('#header').on('click', function() {
        alert("header clicked");
    });

});
```

But if I open the backend I don't see any alert window and also no alert, if I click inside the header textfield.

What is wrong?

**Edit:**
There was an error in the `includeJsFiles` instruction. The right instruction is   `includeJsFiles="{0:'{f:uri.resource(path: \'JS/jquery-3.2.1.min.js\')}', 1:'{f:uri.resource(path: \'JS/crNews.js\')}'}">` ,than it works.

But the jQuery code is required!

Comment: Which version of TYPO3 are you using? Assuming it's probably 9 or 10 the jQuery is most probably included in your BE already. Use inspection tools of your browser to verify that, most probably you'll also find some errors.

Comment: I am using 10.4.14. How can I find out, if jQuery is already loaded for the backend?

Comment: As mentioned, use inspection tools of your browser. You can check it within network tab. Also console will show you JS errors if you'll include libs many times.